# QFileDialog: folder name appears twice under windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4

What I want to do: Simply have the user select a directory within a Qt UI.

The code so far:

```
QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Open directory",
                                                QString::fromStdString(target_dir),
                                                QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

This works just fine under linux. When I cross compile it for windows, though, what happens is that instead of `some_path/directory` it returns `some_path/directory/directory`, that is the name of the selected directory is added twice.

It works fine if I select the folder and happens only when I enter the folder, which should be a thing that the user is able to do.

A reason for this might be that the line edit that in QFileDialog usually contains the file name here contains the folder name and does not clear itself when the folder is entered (which it does under linux).

Now I could write some routine that for a given `QString dir` checks whether it exists and if not and if the last two folders are identical also tries it without the last folder. This is my makeshift solution, but I don't like it, would prefer if I can solve this within parts of the Qt code.

For compatibility reasons, I have to use Qt 4.8.5.

Found nothing on this issue using search engines.

Does anybody know a way to make this work? After all, this should be a very elemental and simple function of Qt.

Edit: Given the advice from p-a-o-l-o, I tried out removing the flags, had the same problem. Then I also tested doing that without the static function:

```
QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
QString dir = dialog.getExistingDirectory(this);
```

Still same problem.

Edit: My makeshift solution, for those who are interested:

```
QString find_next_valid_folder(const QString& path)
{
    if(QDir(path).exists()) return path;
    return find_next_valid_folder(path.left(path.lastIndexOf("/")));
}
```

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the problem here with Qt 4.8.7. May it already have been fixed there? Just to be sure: you open the dialog and then enter a directory as text into the respective text field? I did that, the return value is fine though.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler No, what I that I enter the directory, using only the mouse. At that point, the view shows me being inside the directory. I don't enter anything in the text field - the dialog does that. Under linux, it would go like this: you select the folder, it is in the text field. Then you enter the folder, the view is within it and its name vanishes from the text field. Under windows, it does not vanish.

Comment: Did you try removing the `QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly` option?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Another thing: I haven't tried to compile it directly on windows (whole project would need an extensive setup, maybe I'll create a MVCE later on), I cross-compiled it, which *might* be the issue.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o No, but I will, good idea. However, in the end, I'd like it work with that flag.

Comment: Another thing you could try: instead of the static function, use a `QFileDialog` instance, set it up for directory choosing and see if the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Tested both, sadly not working either. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Aziuth you're still calling the static function on the dialog instance! Call `exec()` on it, instead, and check `getDirectory` right after ...

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o This works sort-of. If I create a `QFileDialog dialog` with the right properties and then call `dialog.directory().path`, it works sort-of, but not if the directory was just selected. Before I continue testing in that direction, I will try out your answer.

Comment: @Aziuth I have tried it exactly as you have described it - no problem here with Qt 4.8.7.

Comment: @Aziuth I edited the answer to address the selection issue (return first item in  `selectedFiles()`, instead of `getDirectory().path()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind refactoring, you can have a simple class like this:

```
    #include <QFileDialog>

    class XFileDialog : public QFileDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        QString _current;
    public:
        XFileDialog(QWidget * parent);
        static QString getExistingDirectory(QWidget * parent = 0, const QString & caption = QString(), const QString & dir = QString(), QFileDialog::Options options = QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
    private slots:
        void folderChanged(const QString &);
    };
```

so you can track `QFileDialog` signals:

```
    XFileDialog::XFileDialog(QWidget * parent) : QFileDialog(parent)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(currentChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(folderChanged(const QString &)));
    }
```

in the slot you simply update the `_current` member:

```
    void XFileDialog::folderChanged(const QString & s)
    {
        if(s.isEmpty()) return;
        _current = s;
    }
```

and implement the `getExistingDirectory` method like this:

```
    QString XFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(QWidget * parent, const QString & caption, const QString & dir, QFileDialog::Options options)
    {
        XFileDialog dialog(parent);

        dialog.setWindowTitle(caption);
        dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
        dialog.setOptions(options);
        dialog.setDirectory(dir);
        if(dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        {
            return dialog._current;
        }
        return QString();
    }
```

Notice the static function returns the last known path the user navigated into.

Now you could replace

```
QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Open directory",
                                                QString::fromStdString(target_dir),
                                                QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks)
```

with

```
QString dir = XFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Open directory",
                                                QString::fromStdString(target_dir),
                                                QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code, but it does not solve the issue. It works identically to the original method, again totally fine on linux but not under my cross compile. Before the edit, it worked if one is within the folder, after the edit, it works when one selects the folder from the outside, just as before.

Comment: I might decide to use that solution and add another condition before the return that checks if the returned file exists, and if not to return the directory. The main issue is still that QFileDialog allows a name to be in the line edit that is invalid (under linux, manually entering something that does not exist in the line edit disables the open button).

Comment: Using a dialog gives you more control, undoubtedly. You can also rely on `QFileDialog` signals, like `directoryEntered` which could help.

Comment: Not sure how to proceed, I'm thinking about editing your answer to match what I made out of it (which is somewhat makeshift) and then accepting it, should we do it like that?

Comment: Edited again to use `QFileDialog` signal. Can you please give it a try?

Comment: Edited your code, lacked a `Q_OBJECT` macro, didn't recognize the slot for that reason. Will test it now. Thanks for your huge support so far.

Comment: Under linux: The code returns the right path if a folder is visually selected, but if one is entered and nothing is selected then, it returns the empty string. I think the reason here is that under linux, the selected file is then set to nothing, which triggers the signal (the slot is called with an empty string). We might solve this by adding something like `if(s.isEmpty()) return;` at the start of the slot, will continue with testing that.

Comment: With the addition, it works. Submitted an edit, will accept your answer as soon as the edit got approved.